# I get a response 'Not authorized to create: TestCase"

Tags: rally

I used Rally API to create a test case. I was able to create test cases with out any issues. However when I used a different login user to create the test case, Rally gives me the following response:

```
{"CreateResult": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "Errors": ["Not authorized to create: TestCase"], "Warnings": ["It is no longer necessary to append \".js\" to WSAPI resources."]}}
```

Comment: Hi, any update on the above issue? Currently this a blocker for me and need to confirm with client that it is a user permission issue :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no indication that this is anything other than a permission issue. Make sure that the new user is not a read-only user and make sure this user has editor rights in the project where you are creating a test case. There are no special API permissions. If you can create a test case in a project using UI you should be able to create a user in the same project with WS API.

Comment: Thank you Nick for your prompt response. The current role for the user is Editor and still not able to create testcase. The user with role Tester was able to add successfully. I will try assiging role as Tester and see

Comment: Adding the Project & workspace reference while test case creation solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a project reference: -

```
JsonObject newObj = new JsonObject();
newObj.addProperty("Project", "789900"); // replace with actual project id
```

***NOTE*** The project ID can be found in the Rally URL itself (if you are pointing to the required project)